# Why does the useState setter receive a mutated state before I actually perform the mutation?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning how useState works deeply through the following component:

```
function MyComponent(){
  const [ obj, setObj ] = useState({nested: {name: 'David'}, password: 'hello'});

  const handleClick = () => {
    setObj(prevObj => {
      console.log(prevObj);
      let newObj = { ...prevObj };
      newObj.nested.name = prevObj.nested.name === 'David' ? 'Mary' : 'David';
      return newObj;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Press</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I understand that this could lead to problems in later stages because the state `prevObj` has been mutated in the line where I assigned `newObj.nested.name` to flip between the values 'David' and 'Mary'. Indeed it is a mutation because `newObj.nested` is the same in reference to `prevObj.nested`, which is part of the component state.

Given this understanding, I would still expect to see `prevObj` logged with property `nested.name` as 'David' on the first button click *because that is the initial value, what the first 'previous value' would have been*. However, this property has value 'Mary' instead. Why is this so?

Also, if `prevObj.nested.name` is 'Mary' as it is so, then wouldn't `newObj.nested.name` remain 'David' on button click by virtue of the assignment and ternary operator?

Note: if I console.log `prevObj.nested` I get an object whose 'name' property has value 'Mary' but if I console.log `prevObj.nested.name` I get the expected 'David'.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects)

Comment: @Konrad thanks for pointing me in this direction. I was testing on codesandbox, maybe not the best place to test JavaScript console behaviour. So I will implement this locally and see whether or not the behaviour is expected.

Comment: It will work the same locally. If you want to know the real value of an object use `console.log(JSON.stringify(prevObj));`